# In postgresql trigger function ------- How can I use NEW variable as an array?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

We can use `NEW.columnname`  and we get it's value.

Can I use `NEW` variable as array to get it's values? like `NEW[1]` or `NEW.1` ...Or if I pass column names in one text array to trigger function argument then can I use `NEW.$1` to get 1st column value?

I have to do it only with **language plpgsql**

Comment: `NEW.column_name` should work; Using the ordinal position is brittle -- it can cause problems if someone changes the column order.

Comment: I am trying NEW.variable     this variable is of type text and contains column_name but NEW.variable recognizes "variable" as key not its value....

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL trigger to generate codes for multiple tables dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392942/postgresql-trigger-to-generate-codes-for-multiple-tables-dynamically)

Comment: Why doesn't your code know what columns it's dealing with? Why do you wish to impose an (assumed) ordering on the columns within a table? You've described a solution you're attempting to implement (which isn't going to work well, if at all) without telling us the underlying problem you're trying to solve - which we may be far better placed to provide suggestions for.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a row / rows to and from array(s), as described [here](http://hype-free.blogspot.com/2008/05/converting-rows-records-to-and-from.html).

Comment: I saw your code but it is not helpful for me because I want to make operation on NEW variable as NEW.in_array[0] this thing is not working

Answer (score 0):

I've suggested a [dup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392942/postgresql-trigger-to-generate-codes-for-multiple-tables-dynamically), since it's really the same underlying issue.

---

I'd be quite enthusiastic to be shown wrong (I occasionally need this myself too), but best I'm aware, referring column names using variables is one of those cases where you actually need to use PL/C triggers rather than PL/PgSQL triggers. You'll find examples of such triggers in contrib/spi and on PGXN.

Alternatively, write a function that writes your trigger [using `execute` statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392942/postgresql-trigger-to-generate-codes-for-multiple-tables-dynamically/6393882#6393882).