# Choose between using EXECUTE and rewriting similar queries in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have virtually the same join query, the difference between my ( >two ) queries being one of the tables on which the join is made. Performance-wise is it better to:
1)rewrite the queries (in one stored procedure ?)    OR
2)pass the table on which  the join is made as a parameter in a  stored procedure (written in plpgsql BTW) and run the query using  EXECUTE

I assume  2) is more elegant  but word is out that by using EXECUTE one cannot benefit from query optimization

Also, what about when i have a varying number of conditions. How can i make sure the query runs in optimal time?  (I take it rewriting the query more than 10 times isn't the way to go :D)

Comment: make sure an index is used every time, don't worry about having duplicate SQL

Answer (score 1):

If you want to benefit from the query optimization, you should definitely rewrite the queries.

It does result in less elegant and longer code, that's harder to maintain, but this is a price sometimes necessary to pay for performance.

Comment: i heard about pgscript which is something like a preprocessor; is this a case where using pgscript is recommended?

Answer (score 1):

There is some overhead for using `execute`, due to repeat planning of the executed query.

For best results *and* maintainability, write a function that writes the various functions you need. Example:

[PostgreSQL trigger to generate codes for multiple tables dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392942/postgresql-trigger-to-generate-codes-for-multiple-tables-dynamically/6393882#6393882)

Comment: is right, but to clarify, `EXECUTE` in PL/pgsql is not the same as `EXECUTE` in PostgreSQL's native SQL environment. `EXECUTE` in PL executes a string (e.g. "EXECUTE 'SELECT ...'"), but `EXECUTE` in SQL dispatches a `PREPARE`'ed query (e.g. "PREPARE some_statement; EXECUTE some_statement...; EXECUTE some_statement...;").

Answer (score 0):

the EXECUTE is dynamic and requires a fresh parse at a minimum - so more overhead.

Answer (score 0):

> 1)rewrite the queries (in one stored
>   procedure ?)

If you have the ability to cache the query plan, do so. Dynamically executing SQL means that the backend needs to re-plan the query every time. Check out [`PREPARE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-prepare.html) for more details on this.

> 2)pass the table on which the join is
>   made as a parameter in a stored
>   procedure (written in plpgsql BTW) and
>   run the query using EXECUTE

Not necessary! [Pl/PgSQL automatically does a `PREPARE`/`EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-PLAN-CACHING) for you. This is one of the primary speed gains that can be had from using Pl/PGSQL. Rhetorical: do you think generating the plan shown in [`EXPLAIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html) was cheap or easy? Cache that chunk of work if at all possible.

> Also, what about when i have a varying
>   number of conditions. How can i make
>   sure the query runs in optimal time?
>   (I take it rewriting the query more
>   than 10 times isn't the way to go :D)

Using individual `PREPARE`ed statements is one way, and the most "bare-metal" way of optimizing the execution of queries. You could do exotic things like using a single set returning PL function that you pass different arguments in to and it conditionally executes different SQL, but I wouldn't recommend it. For optimal performance, stick to `PREPARE`/`EXECUTE` and manage which named statement inside of your application.